# Error compiling dynamic shared c library linux

Tags: c

i try to compile this library "github.com/marzac/rs232/" accordig to this tutorial "http://digego.github.io/extempore/c-xtlang-interop.html" on linux 64 bit machine. 
I am getting this error(s).:

```
robert@hog:~/rs232/rs232$ clang rs232-linux.c -dynamiclib -o librs232.so
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-dynamiclib'
rs232-linux.c:42:9: warning: '__USE_MISC' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define __USE_MISC // For CRTSCTS
        ^
/usr/include/features.h:317:10: note: previous definition is here
# define __USE_MISC     1
         ^
1 warning generated.
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The only thing i found out is that clang is missing the main function because it does not know it is supposed to make a dynamic library. So when i add the "-shared" flag i get this error:

```
robert@hog:~/rs232/rs232$ clang rs232-linux.c -shared -dynamiclib -o librs232.so 
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-dynamiclib'
rs232-linux.c:42:9: warning: '__USE_MISC' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define __USE_MISC // For CRTSCTS
        ^
/usr/include/features.h:317:10: note: previous definition is here
# define __USE_MISC     1
         ^
1 warning generated.
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/rs232-linux-66934f.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/tmp/rs232-linux-66934f.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have nearly no experience in compiling c code or writing c code. 
any help would be very appreciated.

regards,

robert

Comment: The linker is telling you to recompile with `-fPIC`. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: Github has a mechanism to report bugs to the authors of the code... Did you try using that?